# Strange expression

Tags: c

I have found this line of code in a game that I study

```
int charaCode = arc4random() % (126-'!'+1)+'!';
```

I know what arc4random is but the expression is strange to me.

What is the purpose of

```
(126-'!'+1)+'!'
```

It always evaluates to 127.

Comment: that is not the whole expression `i % j + 1` is '(i%j)+1` so that is `(arc4random() % (126-'!'+1)) + '!'`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You interpreted it wrong: the `%` operator has a higher precedence than `+`.

So, in effect, you have:

```
int charaCode = (arc4random() % (126-'!'+1))+'!';
```

which clips the function result to `0..93` and shifts it so that it starts with `'!'`.

So the effective range of what you get is `33..126` (which is the range of all visible ASCII characters from `!` to `~`).

Comment: Important to note that that range contains the value of all visible ascii characters.

Comment: Yes, the effective range is `33..126` (`!`..`~`), not `32..125`.

Comment: thx for edit - got it somehow wrong. Hey ho - thx for all the upvotings! :-)

Answer (score 4):

this is evaluated based on operator precedence like this:

```
(arc4random() % (126-'!'+1)) + '!';
```

Answer (score 2):

`%` has higher precedence than `+`, so your expression isn't same as

```
arc4random() % ((126-'!'+1)) + '!'),
```

but it's the same as

```
(arc4random() % (126-'!'+1)) + '!'
```

First version can return values lower than 33, while second one can't.

Answer (score 1):

that is not the whole expression `i % j + 1` is `(i%j)+1` so that is `(arc4random() % (126-'!'+1)) + '!'`

Doh! I should just post answers ROFL :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are just trying to limit the result to printable characters. Basically it is limiting the range of random numbers to everything between the character "!" and "~".

Comment: If I do arc4random() % (10 + 1) shouldn't the highest possible number be 10?